# PictureBox does not show Grid drawn in a method

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I've got a method CreateGrid():

```
        public void CreateMyGrid() 
    {
        g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {

            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(pen1, cellSize * c, cellSize * r, cellSize, cellSize);
                Cell newCell = new Cell(rows * columns, new Vector(c, r));
                newCell.rectangle = new Rectangle(cellSize * c,
                    cellSize * r,
                    cellSize,
                    cellSize);
                gridList.Add(newCell);
            }
        }

        foreach (Cell cell in gridList)
        {
            if (cell.positionCR.X == start.X && cell.positionCR.Y == start.Y)
            {
                g.DrawImage(potato, cell.rectangle.X + 1, cell.rectangle.Y + 1);
            }

            if (cell.positionCR.X == goal.X && cell.positionCR.Y == goal.Y)
            {
                g.DrawImage(cake, cell.rectangle.X + 1, cell.rectangle.Y + 1);
            }
        }

    }
```

If I call the very same code by Button_Click the grid is drawn. But if I call the method in the constructor like this:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateMyGrid();            
        }
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: Do **not** use CreateGraphics().  If you want to draw into an image then you can with Graphics.FromImage().  If you want to draw to the screen then use the box' Paint event.

Comment: Your Button_Click works because at that time, it draws the grid for you but no Paint event raises, if you try moving your form so that your PictureBox is out of the screen, you will see the grid disappear. `CreateMyGrid()` is placed in the constructor so after showing, there are some raises of `Paint` event which clear all your drawn grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void CreateMyGrid(Graphics g) 
{
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
    {

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(pen1, cellSize * c, cellSize * r, cellSize, cellSize);
            Cell newCell = new Cell(rows * columns, new Vector(c, r));
            newCell.rectangle = new Rectangle(cellSize * c,
                cellSize * r,
                cellSize,
                cellSize);
            gridList.Add(newCell);
        }
    }

    foreach (Cell cell in gridList)
    {
        if (cell.positionCR.X == start.X && cell.positionCR.Y == start.Y)
        {
            g.DrawImage(potato, cell.rectangle.X + 1, cell.rectangle.Y + 1);
        }

        if (cell.positionCR.X == goal.X && cell.positionCR.Y == goal.Y)
        {
            g.DrawImage(cake, cell.rectangle.X + 1, cell.rectangle.Y + 1);
        }
    }

}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){
     CreateMyGrid(e.Graphics);
}
```